# Recover from wstool init failure

Tags: ros, wstool, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the [Installation/Source](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source) and ran the following command:

```
wstool init -j8 src hydro-desktop-wet.rosinstall
```

turtlesim failed to downloads so I stopped the command when running it again:

```
wstool init -j8 src hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
```

I get the following:

```
Error: There already is a workspace config file .rosinstall at "src". Use wstool install/modify.
```

How do I proceed?  I want to be able to run the command again, have it download what's missing (hopefully just turtlesim) and continue on.  This should be documented on the wiki.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115626/recover-from-wstool-init-failure/) by [jkolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/10551/jkolb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Same happened to me, run:

> wstool update -j 4 -t src

and it will continue downloading. Hope it works!

---

Originally posted by [yenn](https://answers.ros.org/users/11191/yenn/) with karma: 26 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
I've seen this asked frequently enough that I added your solution to the source install wiki page: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

**Comment by [jkolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/10551/jkolb/) on 2014-01-24**:
Thanks!  Can you also add a section on keeping a source install up to date?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience with source installations to write that documentation. @dirk-thomas @william or @kruset are probably better candidates for that.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-01-24**:
@ahendrix it is covered here: http://answers.ros.org/question/109656/maintaining-a-ros-source-install-add-packages-update-release/?answer=110961#post-id-110961

@jkolb You commented on the answer above, and declined to fill out a wiki page. I would do it but we are in the middle of a rather big update to the ROS infrastructure. For now I don't have time to do it.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
Ok; I will update the wiki based on those instructions.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-24**:
Wiki updated.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-01-24**:
@ahendrix thanks